# Python code evaluation order?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

The output of following code is

```
5
3
```

I am new to Python, could anybody explain to me why?

```
import sys

def Main():
     str='1+2'
     print eval(str)

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

a = A()
print a.x

if __name__=="__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: On a side-note, see PEP8 (The Python style specification), on function naming conventions. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python code is evaluated from top-down, not from `Main()`.

The interpreter sees the `a = A()` line first, and prints `a.x` which is equal to 5, then it checks for the `if` condition and prints `eval(str)` which is `3`.

Hence the output,

```
 5
 3
```

Comment: Minor detail. Actually, I believe the interpreter sees the `def` and `class` lines first, and it parses the bodies and stores the results in variables. It doesn't evaluate any of the function code while doing so, though.

Comment: @jpmc26 : Yes, you are right. The function definitions are evaluated first, but they are not executed until such time that they are called. :)

Comment: I wasn't sure, so I did some testing. If you add `print 'In class A def!'` inside `A`'s definition (and outside the `__init__` definition, it actually does get printed first. So code inside the `class` definition but outside its functions gets executed when the `class` is parsed.